# How can I link a reference to a movieclip in another AS3 file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages

In my main AS, I am using a MovieClip as a Container despite of the stage.
In another AS file, I want to take the Container as a reference as well as addChild (such as bullets etc) to it, but I really don't know how to write the code.

If I only addChild in the current (sub)AS, it's working, but it's just a problem to removeChild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if I get it right but....

You have a container in your main class and you want to access it from another class, is that right?

I guess what you need is a Globals.as which would look something like this

```
Globals.as // you name it...

package {

  public class Globals extends Object {

      public static var YOUR_REFERENCE_VAR:MovieClip; // This is a static var 

  }

}
```

You need to assign YOUR_REFERENCE_VAR to your MovieClip in your main class. Then anywhere in your project you have access to that MovieClip.

```
package {
  import Globals.as;
  import flash.display.Sprite;

  public class GameEngine extends Sprite  {
      public function GameEngine () {
         addEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onAddedToStage);
      }

      private function _onAddedToStage (evt:Event):void {
         removeEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onAddedToStage);

         //When you to access that MovieClip you access it like this
         Globals.YOUR_REFERENCE_VAR.alpha = 0.5;
      }

  }       
}
```

Now you use addChild/removehild like this

```
var spr:Sprite = new Sprite();
Globals.YOUR_REFERENCE_VAR.addChild (spr);
//Remove the child
Globals.YOUR_REFERENCE_VAR.removeChild (spr);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot^^ it helps me out.

Comment: But a small problem ^^" how can I control the order of addChild, since I addChild from many AS files T_T

Comment: Have in mind that when you use addChild, that child always goes on the top of the display list. If you want to change the index of a particular child use the setChildIndex(yourChild, whatIndex). Keep in mind that you can get the total number of children using numChildren. so you can set a particular children at the top of the list like this... setChildIndex(yourChild, numChildren-1);

Comment: Or you `addChildAt()` to add a child to a specific depth.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your movie clip by reference. Here is a quick example :

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        public function Main() {
            //create your movie clip
            var movieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            //if your MovieClip is in the Flash IDE library setup an export name and do
            //var flasLibraryMovieClip : YourMovieClipExportName = new YourMovieClipExportName()

            //add your movie clip to the display list
            addChild(movieClip);

            //instantiate your second class
            //and pass the movie clip to the class constructor
            var test : Test = new Test(movieClip);      
        }
    }
}


package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Test extends Sprite {
        public function Test(movieClip : MovieClip) {
            //do stuff with the movie
        }       
    }
}
```